# "логарифмические доходности" или "логарифм доходности"?

Tags: недопустимая-метка

Как правильно сказать:
"логарифмические доходности" или "логарифм доходности"?

Answer (score 1):

Вы не совсем по адресу обратились, посмотрите вот употребление терминов на специальном сайте:

> Рассмотрев эти три примера, можно сделать вывод, что суммирование
>   процентных доходностей и средняя арифметическая доходность не отражают
>   реального положения вещей. Чтобы оценить динамику доходности нужны
>   другие инструменты, например **логарифмические или геометрические
>   доходности.** Итак, не вдаваясь в теорию, вернёмся к первому примеру. По
>   каждой неделе рассчитаем натуральные **логарифмы от доходности**,
>   предварительно прибавив к ним единицу. Полученные значения и
>   называются **логарифмическими доходностями.**

https://vk.com/pages?oid=-38372519&p=%D0%9E%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C!